# Trigger c# Event from JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to call c# event from javascript function. I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LikeClick() {
        document.getElementById('<%=Helper.ClientID %>').click();
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Helper" runat="server" OnClick="Helper_Click" />
```

But it doesn't trigger the c# event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't click on an ASP:Button if it is hidden using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276180/i-cant-click-on-an-aspbutton-if-it-is-hidden-using-jquery)

Comment: TL;DR You have to hide the button client side using javascript/css - if you use `Visible="False"`, it's not there in the page at all to be clicked.

Comment: I changed it to display none and visible=true but still nothing happans..

Comment: Then there's something else going on that we can't see from what you've posted.  I assume `LikeClick` is actually called from somewhere?  Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I don't see any error. And yes, the fucntion `LikeClick` is called and working (checked it with an alert).

Comment: try position fixed left 100% top 100% to hide it. I don't think inputs work if they are hidden using display or visibility

Comment: The problem is when its not even hidden it still doesn't work.
Even if its like that: `<asp:Button ID="Helper" runat="server" OnClick="Helper_Click" />`

Comment: Does it work if you actually click the button itself?

Comment: Yes. It working

Comment: if you view source or inspect element, has it correctly inserted the client id in the `getElementById()`?

Comment: It shows this:`document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_Helper').click();`
the webform inherits from a masterpage and its inside ContentPlaceHolder. That might be the problem?

Comment: Where do you call LikeClick?

Comment: I'm creating buttons dynamically: `content += "<button class='btn btn-info' runat='server' style='margin-left:4%' id='Like" + dr[0].ToString() + "' OnClick='LikeClick()'>";` But when i click this button it does active the function because if I put an alert in it it does work.

Comment: Calling `.click()` from JS on an element will trigger a client-side JS "click" event, if any such event is declared. It doesn't look like it is in this case. If you want to cause a server-side button click, you need to use ASP.NET's JS __doPostBack function, and pass the button ID as an argument to it. See http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.5

Comment: @ADyson yes but that will already be wired up to the button won't it? OP says the button works if he clicks it, so calling `click()` should invoke the button handler (client) which calls `__doPostBack()`. or have I got that wrong?

Comment: So you are saying that this `document.getElementById('<%=Helper.ClientID %>').click();` is wrong? Because as i said it does active the func LikeClick().

Comment: No, I don't think it is wrong. TBH it's been a while since I touched webforms, I'm just looking up so some old code now to see if I can offer anything helpful. to me it looks ok.....

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for helping.

Comment: @DaveBecker I kind of assumed that might be the case...but if OP is saying it doesn't work, then perhaps not. It's been a while since I've touched WebForms as well, and very rarely messed with this sort of thing anyway, so the memory eludes me. (Hence commenting and not answering outright!). Maybe something for OP to try out and see what happens. No harm in replacing `document.getElementById('<%=Helper.ClientID %>').click();` with `__doPostBack('Helper', null);` just to see if it works?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: wow. Change `<asp:Button>` to `<asp:LinkButton>` and it worked perfectly for me. Don't ask why :)

Comment: I don't know if I should laugh or cry haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ADyson I literally just did that and nothing. worse still `__doPostBack()` wasn't even defined with just an `<asp:Button>`. From memory I think a button does a native `form.submit()` where as a link is wired to `__doPostBack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a `<asp:Button>` will natively post the form back without a client side event handler. You need a control that does not natively post back but instead uses a client side click handler to call the `__doPostBack()` function.

Change

`<asp:Button ID="Helper" runat="server" OnClick="Helper_Click" />`

to this

`<asp:LinkButton ID="Helper" runat="server" OnClick="Helper_Click" />`